# Lot of repetition in React component

Tags: reactjs, structure

I have a rather large React component that manages the display of a detail for a job on my site.

There are a few things that I would like to do smarter

1. The component has a few options for opening Dialogs. For each dialog I have a separate Open and Close function. For example  `handleImageGridShow` and `handleImageGridClose`. Is there any way to be more concise around this?
2. I have many presentational components (e.g. `ViewJobDetails`) that shows details about the job. My issue is that I have to pass them down into each Component as a prop and I'm passing the same props over and over again
3. As I'm loading my data from firebase I often have to do similar checks to see if the data exists before I render the component (`e.g.this.state.selectedImageGrid && <ImageGridDialog />`). Is there any more clever way of going about this?

   import React, { Component } from 'react';

   ```
   import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
   import ViewJobAttachment from "../../components/jobs/viewJobAttachment";
   import ViewJobDetails from "../../components/jobs/viewJob/viewJobDetails";
   import ViewJobActions from "../../components/jobs/viewJob/viewJobActions";
   import ViewCompanyDetails from "../../components/jobs/viewJob/viewCompanyDetails";
   import ViewClientsDetails from "../../components/jobs/viewJob/viewClientsDetails";
   import ViewProductsDetails from "../../components/jobs/viewJob/viewProductsDetails";
   import ViewAttachmentDetails from "../../components/jobs/viewJob/viewAttachmentDetails";
   import ViewEventLogDetails from "../../components/jobs/viewJob/viewEventLogDetails";
   import ViewSummaryDetails from "../../components/jobs/viewJob/viewSummary";
   import {FirebaseList} from "../../utils/firebase/firebaseList";
   import SimpleSnackbar from "../../components/shared/snackbar";
   import {calculateTotalPerProduct} from "../../utils/jobsService";
   import BasicDialog from "../../components/shared/dialog";
   import ImageGrid from "../../components/shared/imageGrid";
   import Spinner from "../../components/shared/spinner";
   import ViewPinnedImageDialog from "../../components/jobs/viewEntry/viewPinnedImage";
   import {
     Redirect
   } from 'react-router-dom';

   const styles = theme => ({
     wrapper: {
       marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit*2
     },
     rightElement: {
       float: 'right'
     }
   });

   const ImageGridDialog = (props) => {
     return (
       <BasicDialog open={!!props.selectedImageGrid}
                    handleRequestClose={props.handleRequestClose}
                    fullScreen={props.fullScreen}
                    title={props.title}
       >
         <ImageGrid selectedUploads={props.selectedImageGrid}
                        handleClickOpen={props.handleClickOpen}/>
       </BasicDialog>
     )
   };

   class ViewJob extends Component {
     constructor() {
       super();

       this.state = {
         currentJob: null,
         entries: [],
         promiseResolved: false,
         attachmentDialogOpen: false,
         openAttachment: null,
         selectedImageGrid: false,
         selectedPinnedImage: false,
         showSnackbar: false,
         snackbarMsg: '',
         markedImageLoaded: false,
         loading: true,
         redirect: false
       };

       this.firebase = new FirebaseList('jobs');

       this.handleJobStatusChange = this.handleJobStatusChange.bind(this);
       this.handleImageGridShow = this.handleImageGridShow.bind(this);
       this.handleImageGridClose = this.handleImageGridClose.bind(this);
       this.handlePinnedImageClose = this.handlePinnedImageClose.bind(this);
       this.handlePinnedImageShow = this.handlePinnedImageShow.bind(this);
       this.handleMarkedImageLoaded = this.handleMarkedImageLoaded.bind(this);
       this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
       this.pushLiveToClient = this.pushLiveToClient.bind(this);
     }

     componentDidMount() {
       this.firebase.db().ref(`jobs/${this.props.id}`).on('value', (snap) => {
         const job = {
           id: snap.key,
           ...snap.val()
         };
         this.setState({
           currentJob: job,
           loading: false
         })
       });

       const previousEntries = this.state.entries;

       this.firebase.db().ref(`entries/${this.props.id}`).on('child_added', snap => {
         previousEntries.push({
           id: snap.key,
           ...snap.val()
         });

         this.setState({
           entries: previousEntries
         })
       });
     }

     handleRemove() {
       this.firebase.remove(this.props.id)
         .then(() => {
           this.setState({redirect: true})
         })
     };

     pushLiveToClient() {
       const updatedJob = {
         ...this.state.currentJob,
         'lastPushedToClient': Date.now()
       };
       this.firebase.update(this.state.currentJob.id, updatedJob)
         .then(() => this.handleSnackbarShow("Job pushed live to client"))
     }

     handleJobStatusChange() {
       const newState = !this.state.currentJob.completed;
       const updatedJob = {
         ...this.state.currentJob,
         'completed': newState
       };
       this.firebase.update(this.state.currentJob.id, updatedJob)
     }

     handleSnackbarShow = (msg) => {
       this.setState({
         showSnackbar: true,
         snackbarMsg: msg
       });
     };

     handleSnackbarClose= (event, reason) => {
       if (reason === 'clickaway') {
         return;
       }
       this.setState({ showSnackbar: false });
     };

     handleAttachmentDialogClose =() => {
       this.setState({attachmentDialogOpen: false})
     };

     handleClickOpen = (file) => {
       this.setState({
         attachmentDialogOpen: true,
         openAttachment: file
       });
     };

     handleImageGridShow(imageGrid) {
       this.setState({selectedImageGrid: imageGrid})
     }

     handleImageGridClose() {
       this.setState({selectedImageGrid: false})
     }

     handlePinnedImageShow(pinnedImage) {
       this.setState({selectedPinnedImage: pinnedImage})
     }

     handlePinnedImageClose() {
       this.setState({selectedPinnedImage: false})
     }

     handleMarkedImageLoaded() {
       this.setState({markedImageLoaded: true})
     }

     render() {
       const {classes} = this.props;
       let {_, costPerItem} = calculateTotalPerProduct(this.state.entries);
       if (this.state.redirect) {
         return <Redirect to='/jobs' push/>
       } else {
         if (this.state.loading) {
           return <Spinner/>
         } else {
           return (
             <div className={styles.wrapper}>
               {this.state.currentJob &&
               <div>
                 <ViewJobActions currentJob={this.state.currentJob}
                                 handleJobStatusChange={this.handleJobStatusChange}
                                 pushLiveToClient={this.pushLiveToClient}
                 />
                 <ViewJobDetails currentJob={this.state.currentJob}/>
                 <ViewCompanyDetails currentJob={this.state.currentJob}/>
                 <ViewClientsDetails currentJob={this.state.currentJob}/>
                 <ViewProductsDetails currentJob={this.state.currentJob}/>
                 {this.state.currentJob.selectedUploads && this.state.currentJob.selectedUploads.length > 0
                   ? <ViewAttachmentDetails currentJob={this.state.currentJob} handleClickOpen={this.handleClickOpen}/>
                   : null}
                 <ViewEventLogDetails jobId={this.state.currentJob.jobId}
                                      jobKey={this.state.currentJob.id}
                                      entries={this.state.entries}
                                      handlePinnedImageShow={this.handlePinnedImageShow}
                                      handleImageGridShow={this.handleImageGridShow}/>
                 <ViewSummaryDetails stats={costPerItem}/>
                 <ViewJobAttachment open={this.state.attachmentDialogOpen}
                                    handleRequestClose={this.handleAttachmentDialogClose}
                                    attachment={this.state.openAttachment}
                 />
                 {this.state.selectedImageGrid &&
                 <ImageGridDialog selectedImageGrid={this.state.selectedImageGrid}
                                  handleRequestClose={this.handleImageGridClose}
                                  handleClickOpen={this.handleClickOpen}
                                  title="Pictures for job"
                                  fullScreen={false}/>}
                 {this.state.selectedPinnedImage &&
                 <ViewPinnedImageDialog attachment={this.state.selectedPinnedImage}
                                        open={!!this.state.selectedPinnedImage}
                                        markedImageLoaded={this.state.markedImageLoaded}
                                        handleMarkedImageLoaded={this.handleMarkedImageLoaded}
                                        handleRequestClose={this.handlePinnedImageClose}
                                        otherMarkedEntries={this.state.entries}
                 />
                 }
                 <SimpleSnackbar showSnackbar={this.state.showSnackbar}
                                 handleSnackbarClose={this.handleSnackbarClose}
                                 snackbarMsg={this.state.snackbarMsg}/>

               </div>}
             </div>
           );
         }
       }
     }
   }

   export default withStyles(styles)(ViewJob);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a regular component method and bind it in handler like this `onSomething={this.handler.bind(this, index)}` assuming you have some distinguishable thing in the index var

function should look like this

```
handler(index) {
  ...
}
```